# Create a grid of rectangles on a leaflet.js map

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

How can I divide a leaflet.js map in a grid of rectangles, such that for every
rectangle that I click a different event is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the height and width of the container in pixels, calculate appropriate dimensions for the amount of columns and rows you want, create rectangles of that size and add them to the map in a FeatureGroup, then attach a click handler to the featureGroup with `.on`. You will probably want to mark each rectangle's options object with some unique identifier.